# Magic Square Other Diagonal

Tags: java, magic-square

My other diagonal method won't work correctly.

```
public int sumOtherDiag()
{
   int otherDiag = 0;
   for (int i = 0; i < square.length−1; i++)
   {
      otherDiag += square[i][i];
   }
   return otherDiag;
}
```

I don't have my output to show here, but is there anything that someone sees wrong right off the bat?

This method is supposed to add the elements and get the sum of the second diagonal (starting from the right - down) of a magic square. 
For example, if my square was

```
01 04 03

03 05 04

05 02 04
```

It would **output**

`03 + 05 + 05 = and get 13`

But my actual output is printing a number less than what it is supposed too.

(It's hard to explain without my output. I will upload that later when I get access to my program)

Any help will be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: What's it supposed to do, and what does it do instead?

Comment: why i < square.length−1 ? why not i < square.length? show us your input at least plz

Comment: Because this diagonal starts from the end of the row and adds the sums of the numbers diagonal from there.

Comment: To solve this problem, write down the _coordinates_ (i.e. array subscripts) of the cells you want to add up, in order from top right to bottom left (or the other direction if you want).  Then figure out what it will take to make your loop access them.

Answer (score 1):

```
public int sumOtherDiag()
{
   int otherDiag = 0;
   int count = square.length;
   for (int i = 0; i < square.length; i++)
   {
      otherDiag += square[i][--count];
   }
   return otherDiag;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's break down your code to see what you did and what you wanted :

with your one loop that you have your coordinates are `[0,0]` , `[1,1]` and you missed out `[2,2]` based on my knowledge because you chose your last index to be  less than `square.length−1`, and you must know index start from zero to less than `square.lenght` .

if you run your this code :

```
int[][] array = {{01, 04, 03},
        {03, 05, 04},
        {05, 02, 04}
        };
        int otherDiag = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(array[i][i]);
        }
```

your outcome would be this

```
1
5
4
```

and you if you chose `array.lenght-1` to be excluded your output is

```
1
5
```

As you see you left the last index which is 4, which I am sure this is not what you are looking for.

**You want to have summation of diagonal elements not vertical elements**

The coordinates that you want are

`[0,2]` , `[1,1]`, and `[2,0]`

Used my sample as a **blue print** to figure out what you want

**For example**, suppose `x = new int[3][4]`, `x[0]`, `x[1]`, and `x[2]` are one-dimensional
arrays and each contains four elements, as shown in the figure `x.length` is `3`, and
`x[0].length`, `x[1].length`, and `x[2].length` are `4`

[image]

How to traverse and intilize the 2D array you can follow following sample as your **blue print**:

[image]